# JqGrid not able to bind JSON data with "dot"

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have a JSON response from server which I am trying to bind to JQgrid. However, the response is a JSON string has "dot" as a part of the object name. I am unable to get the JQGrid work with the "dot"

Here is the sample fiddle for the problem I am facing  http://jsfiddle.net/sharathchandramg/rpdfrb0L/2/

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
data: data,
datatype: "local",
height: 250,
colNames: ['Name', 'Cluster', 'Location'],
colModel: [{
    name: 'name',
    width: 120
}, {
    name: 'metrics.cluster.first.value',
    width: 60,
    jsonmap: function (obj) {

        return obj.metrics['cluster.first'].value
    }
}, {
    name: 'metrics.location-latitude.value',
    width: 60
}, ],
caption: "Example"  
});
```

As shown the fiddle, I am not able to bind the property "cluster.first" even while using jsonmap. Whereas if the property name is "location-latitude" the grid works fine.

Let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: can you post the mock up data?

Comment: The fiddle link has the sample mock data I am using for testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is very easy. The property `jsonmap` will be ignored in case of usage `datatype: "local"` in jqGrid 4.6. I changed the behavior in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) (see [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/The-usage-of-jsonmap-with-local-data)). So one possible solution will be to use free jqGrid 4.8 or higher instead of jqGrid 4.6.

One more simple way to solve the problem will be usage of `datatype: "jsonstring"`. You can verified

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    datastr: data,
    datatype: "jsonstring",
    height: "auto",
    colNames: ['Name', 'Cluster', 'Location'],
    colModel: [{
        name: 'name',
        width: 120
    }, {
        name: 'metrics_cluster_first_value',
        width: 60,
        jsonmap: function (obj) {
            return obj.metrics['cluster.first'].value
        }
    }, {
        name: 'metrics_location_latitude_value',
        jsonmap: 'metrics.location-latitude.value',
        width: 60
    }],
    caption: "Example"
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/rpdfrb0L/5/. You can see additionally that I changed `name` property of all `colModel` items to have no dots inside. I recommend to follow the rule always.

Comment: Also to add on this, if jsonstring is used, then data should be provided via the datastr attribute

Comment: @RamanathanMuthuraman: Yes, of cause, See the code of my answer. the input for `datatype: "jsonstring"` is `datastr`, which can contains object and not only the JSON string.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get it working using latest sources. Will the same thing work if I need to bind both column headers and data dynamically?

Comment: @SharathChandra: You are welcome! Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean under "to bind both column headers and data dynamically". Which kind of binding you mean? You question was about reading of *data*. The texts in the column header are independent from the reading of the data.

Comment: @Oleg, the sample response I have shown in fiddle comes from server. Based on the response I am trying to create the grid dynamically (using colName and colModel). I was facing issue when trying to bind colModel where object has "dot". Sample is attached here <https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=CC616714B2E0FBD9%212788>

Comment: Yes Oleg, you have given it in the code but just wanted to document it as a comment

Comment: @SharathChandra: Sorry, but what is your question now? The code which you posted have some small problems, but all are not related to the question about reading JSON data. For example you don't included jQuery UI css which is required, you can add `dataType: "json"` option to Ajax request from `url: "data/sample.json"`. After that you can remove `var jsonRes = $.parseJSON(responce);` bacause jQuery.ajax will do this. The `jsonmap` which you use in the example don't contains any dots and you can just use `jsonmap: "metrics.cluster-first.value"`

Comment: @SharathChandra: It's more safe to set `jsonmap` based on the input names and to use some standard texts like `"c1"`, `"c2"`, ... as the column names (the value of `name` property). The reason: you use HTML5 (`<!DOCTYPE html>`) which don't allow to use spaces or some other special characters in ids, but `name` property of `colModel` will be used to build ids of internal elements of jqGrid. So common input data can produce the problem in usage `"name": key` which you use currently.

Comment: @Oleg, thanks for the detailed explanation. I was looking @ using jsonmap: "metrics.cluster.first.value" or jsonmap: "metrics[cluster.first].value" since the data received from server will have dots. I am facing issues with parsing the data containing dots

Comment: @Oleg, Based on your suggestions, I was able to get it working for dot notation also. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @SharathChandra: You are welcome! If you "dynamically" enumerate properties of `metrics` then you can always use function form of `jsonmap`: `var propName; for (propName in metricsLink) { if (metricsLink.hasOwnProperty(propName)) { gridModel.push({ "name": key, jsonmap: function (obj) { return obj.metrics[propName].value; } } }`