# JQgrid FreezeColumn not freezing headers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I am new to JQgrid and have been attempting to freeze the first column in the grid so horizontal scrolling will not effect that column.

I have `frozen: true` in the `colModel`, as well as calling `Jquery("#grid").jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');`.

This correctly freezes the column DATA, but as I scroll to the right, the column headers scroll with me. How can I freeze the headers too?

Thank you very much!

Sample Code:

```
jQuery("#taskGrid").jqGrid({
datatype: "jsonstring",
colNames:['task ID','TASK Name', 'ROLE Info'],
colModel:[
    {name:'taskId',index:'taskId', width:100, frozen: true},
    {name:'taskName',index:'taskName', width:200},
    {name: 'roleInfo.1', index: 'roleInfo.1', width:100, formatter: 'checkbox' }

],
jsonReader: {repeatitems: false},
datastr: JSON.parse(document.form.taskData.value),
rowNum:50,
pager: '#pager2',
sortname: 'taskId',
viewrecords: true,
sortorder: "desc",
caption:"JSON Example",
height: "750", 
width: "350",
shrinkToFit: false
});jQuery("#taskGrid").jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');
```

Comment: What version of jqGrid are you using? I think it didn't work correctly in some older versions. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8486592/1491895 says it was implemented in 4.3. It works in the demo at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8486592/1491895

Comment: @Barmar I'm using version 5.1.0.  Other than the fact that I am using datatype: jsonstring and a datastr, my grid is very similar to that demo. 

Haven't seen anything online about it being IE11 incompatible, but that is the browser I am working with.

Comment: @newToJQGrid: Try to use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.13.4 instead of Guriddo jqGrid JS 5.1.0, which you use currently. First of all it includes many fixes in frozen columns, contains many enhancements and its free in opposite to Guriddo jqGrid JS (see the prices [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)). To try free jqGrid you can just use load all jqGrid directly from CDN (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)).

Comment: @newToJQGrid: I'd recommend you additionally to consider to use `datatype: "local"` and `data: jQuery.parseJSON(document.form.taskData.value)` instead of `datatype: "jsonstring"` and `datastr`. The information from [here](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) could be interesting for you too if jqGrid is new for you.

Comment: @Oleg: thank you for the recommendation. After switching to datatype: "local" and to free jqGrid, the freezing works as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.13.4 instead of Guriddo jqGrid JS 5.1.0, which you use currently. First of all it includes many fixes in frozen columns, contains many enhancements and its free in opposite to Guriddo jqGrid JS (see the prices [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)). To try free jqGrid you can just use load all jqGrid directly from CDN (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)).

I'd recommend you additionally to use `datatype: "local"` and `data: jQuery.parseJSON(document.form.taskData.value)` instead of `datatype: "jsonstring"` and `datastr`. The datatype `"jsonstring"` is good only if you need *to prevent* local sorting of input data during initial loading. If you would use `datatype: "local"` then the input data will be **sorted locally** based on `sortname: 'taskId'` and `sortorder: "desc"` before there will be displayed.

Comment: I am a little confused based on a few of your comments in different threads. I see you suggesting  `datatype: "jsonstring"` for users attempting to use `jsonmap` in the `colModel`.  I have been attempting to bind nested JSON data in my grid.  Should I make a new question?

Comment: @newToJQGrid: Sorry, what you mean? Which comments, which threads?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30255044/jqgrid-not-able-to-bind-json-data-with-dot

Comment: @newToJQGrid: And where you see some problems? Why you are confused? Do you use dots in the JSON data? You don't posted any **example of your JSON data**. `'roleInfo.1'` means not the property with the name `'roleInfo.1'`, but the statement like `'item.roleInfo.1'` or `'item.roleInfo[1]'`, where the `item` represent the row. Which data you have as the input for jqGrid?

Comment: created new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39213851/jqgrid-getrowdata-is-not-the-same-format-as-local-input-data

Comment: @newToJQGrid: Why you deleted the question? What you need to do can be solved in different ways. First of all you should simplify `colModel` and to fix it. Second you can just convert original complex data structures to simple objects, fill simple data in jqGrid, edit simple data, get simple result of editing and convert the results of editing in the original complex format before sending to the server. Alternatively you have to use `convertOnSave` and `saveLocally` properties of `colModel` (see [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Editing-of-local-data))